# How to Manage (and preferably clear) the `Frequently contacted` list in the Favourites tab

Tags: logging, history

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3, with Adroid Version 4.4.2

If you click on <kbd>Phone</kbd> and then go to <kbd>Favourites</kbd> (The 3rd Tab at the top), you will see 1 or 2 lists:

1. Favourites
2. Frequently contacted

I want to know what contributes to contacts being in the `Frequently contacted`? (SMS, Calls Durations, WhatsApp, Emails)

And secondly, how do I remove a contact from this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a galaxy s4 with 4.4.2. I realize that Touchwiz is a bit different between the two devices but maybe this will help.

I can't tell you for sure what contributes to the ranking on the list but it seems to me that it's based on number of calls primarily. There is no one in my favorites list that I have not made a call to and I have many contacts not on the favorites list that I only sms, email, etc,  with.

As far as removing a contact, I can hit the menu button and have an option "Remove from Favorites" which brings up a checkbox list allowing me to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this issue.

1. Open Favorites in your phone - your Favorites list should appear.
2. Open menu (bottom left of Home button) - 4 options should appear.

   - Add to favorites
   - Remove from favorites
   - Grid view
   - Settings
3. Select *Remove from favorites* - boxes should then appear next to names.
4. Select the names you wish to remove.
5. Select *Done* in top right.

Comment: Also figured it out some time ago, thanks. Nice logical flow of steps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings - general - application manager - all- contact storage the clear cash